# Связь многие ко многим MySql

Tags: mysql

Описано много примеров как создать связь многие ко многим. 
Я же хочу понять как вставлять данные, обновлять и делать выборки.

**Есть 3 таблицы**

[image: База данных]

---

Таблица **camps** - рекламные кампании

[image: camps - структура]

[image: camps - данные]

---

Таблица **geo_items** - коды стран

[image: geo_items - структура]

[image: geo_items - данные]

---

Таблица связей **camps_geo**

[image: camps_geo - структура]

[image: camps_geo - связи]

[image: camps_geo - данные]

---

Например я хочу добавить новую рекламную кампанию с такими данными:

```
array(
   'camp_name' => 'Тестовая рекламная кампания'
   'geo' => 'RU, UA, KZ'
)
```

---

Далее я хочу сделать выборку.

Скриптом я определил что у юзера гео "**RU**",
как выбрать все кампании у которых в гео есть "**RU**"

---

Так же если у кампании кроме ГЕО есть еще критерии по браузерам.
Я создам таблицу с браузерами, таблицу связей для нее.

Потом скриптом определяю ГЕО и браузер юзера, и мне нужно выбрать кампании у которыx есть совпадения по ГЕО и по браузеру.

А дальше там еще операционная система и т.д. ...

В общем покажите как делать такие выборки и как вставлять и обновлять данные для кампаний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выборки по гео

```
SELECT camps.name FROM camps 
INNER JOIN camps_geo ON camps_geo.camp_id = camps.id
INNER JOIN geo_items ON camps_geo.geo_id = geo_items.id
WHERE geo_items.geocode = 'RU'
```

Ну а для создания компании с гео, если вы используете нативный php и mysql то делать придется по очереди: 1) добавляем компанию, берем ее id. 2)проверяем есть ли эти гео в geo_items, если есть вытягиваем их id если нет то заносим и вытягиваем id. 3) приводим все данные к правильному виду и инсертим в camps_geo

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только что игрался с join-ами и получилось так `select *
from camps
join camps_geo
join geo_items 
where geo_items.geocode = 'RU'
and camps.id = camps_geo.camp_id`

Comment: ну это тоже самое что я и написал, только у меня это более верный способ, связи таблиц лучше описывать в операторе ON